# How to check the host name and Ip

Tags: unix

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Current date : $(date) @ $(hostname)"
echo "Network configuration"
/sbin/ifconfig
```

I have local machine and remote machine. Now my question using my local machine(windows), how to check the remote machine host name and ifconfig information ?

Thanks,
palani

Comment: `echo %COMPUTERNAME% && ipconfig`

Comment: you need to either one to get the other. Example, if you know the IP, you can get the hostname